# Can't call function onSubmit from embedded form element

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, reactjs, onsubmit

Using Meteor as backend and MongoDB as the database, I want to update an existing document. I'd like to show the existing values of the input/textarea fields on page load, so one can see them before editing.

The reason below code does not work is, I think, because there's two `return` functions that are called and I have the form embedded within one. I need to wrap the `form` within this function below, because I want to show the existing values as the values of the input fields.

```
{this.data.theActionToUpd.map(function (act) {
```

Therefore one can not directly call the `updateItem()` function with `onsubmit={this.updateItem}`.

So what's the proper way of handling this?

```
EditAction = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData: function() {
    var id = this.props.params.id;
    return {
      theActionToUpd: MyActions.find({
        '_id': id
      }).fetch()
    };  
  },

  updateItem: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.actionTitleUpd).value;

    MyActions.update({$set: {
      'title': title
    }});
    console.log(id);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.data.theActionToUpd.map(function (act) {
            return  (
            <form onSubmit={this.updateItem} key={act._id}>
              <input type="text" ref="actionTitleUpd" defaultValue={`${act.title}`} />
              <button type="submit">Update Action</button>
            </form>
          )
        })}
      </div>

    ); 
  }

});
```

Comment: I doubt this is duplicate. And if it is, I still don't get what the answer is.

Comment: Please check the answer - you're referencing the `updateItem` method inside a `.map` operation, which uses a different scope for `this` inside it. Any of the three methods at the linked answer will fix this problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks my friend! :D